# Designing a Turing machine for $a^n$ $b^{2n}$ $a^n$

Tags: automata, turing-machines

I am new to theory of automata, and i have a little knowledge of designing a turing machine,
I am stuck in this question which is given to us as an assignment,

$\{$$a^n$ $b^{2n}$ $a^n$ : $n\geq0$$\}$ over $\{a,b\}$

what I want from you all is that please help me understand the problem, I don't want anyone to solve it for me because I want to do it myself, I just need a little help to design a turing machine for this problem. Thanks

Comment: You know something about the URM-machine? If no: it is a Touring-machine equivalent and this problem is much easier to solve with it, but nevermind. If yes: I suggest you to solve the problem with it and claim "Because of the equivalence of this 2 machine exist a Touring machine that accepts $\{a^nb^{2n}c^n : n\geq 0\}$

Comment: No, I don't have any idea about URM-machine. Our instructor told us to do it only using turing machine, I want to make a basic idea for this problem that what will be my approach or the algorithm I used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the head right until you find a $b$, than using a 4° symbol $o$ to "cancel" pair of letter a,b until you don't have any $a$, then travel right until you found a $c$ and repeat. This is the general idea (but it'll be my way, I'm not used to work with touring machine and may be quite overcomplicated) and will need a lot of adjustment and you will have to consider a lot of subcase and situation.